# Set specific rows of matrices in cell array to zero without using a for-loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization, cell-array

I'd like to replace a specific number of elements of my cell to zero without using for. For example to replace elements of row 2 in example cell a below: How should I proceed possibly using cellfun?

```
a=cell(2,3);
cellfun(@(x)(zeros(a{x}(2,:))),a);
```

It gives the error "Bad cell reference operation".
what if I'd like to make row 2 empty again?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: do you just have one cell? or do you have a cell array with multiple matrices? please be more specific.

Comment: `cellfun` is not really designed to do replacement operations, you will need a separate function to do the job, which will make you code less readable. Why do you want to avoid `for` loops ? It seems much more appropriate in your case.

Comment: @thewaywewalk In fact, I've multiple cells and I'd like to make the second row of each cell to zero.

Comment: @Ratbert. I thought cell-fun can be replaced whenever there's a specific function for doing the jobs and it would be faster. if it is not the case, for loop is easy alternative.

Comment: do the matrices in the cell have all the same size?

Comment: @thewaywewalk, No,they have different sizes.

Comment: then I'd also recommend to follow the advice of @Ratbert and just use a for loop.

Comment: ok,, I'll do it. just what was the learning point? cellfun not good when working with multiple varying size cell & not good for replacement purpose?

Comment: just to clarify; you want something like `a = 

[    {1}    {1}    {1};
    {0}   {0}    {0} ]` In that case i would recomend a look at `deal`. Its a one-liner then : `[a(2,:)]={deal(0)}`

Comment: @hamideh the main problem is, that the action you want to perform requires an assignment with `=`. There actually would be a solution to your question using `eval`, but it is considered really bad practice. Thats why nobody posts it as an answer, in combination with `cellfun` it won't be faster than the loop anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action you want to perform requires an assignment within a function. The only way to achieve this is using [**`eval`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), which is considered [**bad practice**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/).

A loop is therefore the best remaining option, if you want to keep everything in one script:

```
A = {randn(2,3),randn(2,3)};
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    A{ii}(2,:) = 0;
end
```

If you don't bother using multiple files, you can put the assignment in a function:

```
function [ out ] = setZero( cellarray, rowidx )

out = cellarray;
out(rowidx,:) = 0;

end
```

and use it as follows:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) setZero(x,2),A ,'uni',0)
```

Comment: Using `eval` is not the only way. You can transform the matrix so that the second row becomes all zero. Assigning second row to zero is not the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a transformation that turns a given matrix `A` to a matrix where the second row is all-zero. Here are three alternatives

```
A=cellfun(@(x) [x(1,:); zeros(size(x(2,:))); x(3:end,:)], A, 'uni', 0)
```

and

```
A=cellfun(@(x) diag(1:size(x,1)~=2)*x, A, 'uni', 0)
```

and

```
A=cellfun(@(x) bsxfun(@times, (1:size(x,1))' ~= 2, x), A, 'uni', 0)
```

The first one is the most robust one because it will handle the cases that your matrix has `NaN` elements. The second and third alternatives simply multiply the second row by zero. The second achieves this by multiplying it with a diagonal matrix where all diagonal elements are `1` except element `(2,2)` which is zero. The third alternative achieves this using `bsxfun`.

This is to demonstrate that you can achieve this without for loops however a simple for loop is much more readable.